# "Check if you are using third party repositories" what this means while upgrading?

Tags: update-manager

I am getting an error message while updating Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

The error messege is:

```
"Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get-install-f"
```

I tried to run the above command in terminal but it is also showing an error.

Can someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 5):

The message is clear. Something went wrong and it's most likely because some non-Ubuntu repository in your system. You can disable them using many ways, but my favourite is:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ /etc/apt/sources.list.d.bk/
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

Comment: Would you please explain what this does and why it is a solution to the problem? Making the apt sources list blank, which is what this seems to do, seems unintuitive, and not the sort of thing people ought to be encouraged to do blindly.

Comment: @markling it doesn't make the software list go blank, only the third party ones and even then isn't as aggressive doing that, since it doesn't touch the sources.list file, which is where default repositories reside, that you can actually also add 3rd party ones there. This solution addresses OP message "Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them" and this answer achieve that in the safest way possible.

Comment: Thanks. Please do give a clear description of what it does do and how it works!